# HOW TO PRINT 1,000,000 IN PYTHON AS IT IS I KNOW WHY IT IS PRINTED AS 1 0 0 BUT HOW TO PRINT IT AS IT IS? WITHOUT CONSIDRING 1,000,000 A STRING

Tags: python, optimization, printing, code-snippets

input-print(1,000,000)
output-1 0 0

Comment: relax, no need to use CAPS LOCK in the title

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
numbers = "{:,}".format(5000000)
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is equal to

```py
print(1, 0, 0)
```

which is to print out three separate things: the number one, the number zero, and another number zero. For a decimal separator in python, you can use `_`, so if you try

```py
print(1_000_000)
```

or just plain old

```py
print(1000000)
```

But if you really want that `,`, you need to print out a string instead. e.g.

```py
print("1,000,000")
```

Comment: ohh i am extranmly sory for being too dumb thanks dude for helping me out